# How does one make a Stream from a Map with Dart

Tags: dart, stream

With Dart, I can make a Stream object from a List using `Stream.fromIterable(list)`. But what if I want to stream over a Map() such as `var map={"a":1, "b":2, 3:4, 6:5}`;

Comment: `Stream.fromIterable(map.entries)`?

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. Thanks. I am adding sample code below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@jamesdlin has the answer I was looking for. Here is an example:

```
  Map<dynamic, int> map = {1: 1, 'a': 10, 'b': 20, 3: 2, 4: 4, 6: 5};
  Stream stream = Stream.fromIterable(map.entries);

  await stream
      .where((i) => i.key.runtimeType == int)
      .listen((i) => print(i.value))
      .onDone(() => print("done"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious what that would be a stream of. Smaller maps might be one way, or 2-element arrays (like a Python tuple). A generator function would be the way to do it:

```
Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> mapStream(Map source) async* {
    for (var k in source.keys) {
        yield { "key": k, "value": source[k] };
    }
}
```